# How does one escape backticks in markdown?

Tags: escaping, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, backticks

I am writing some documentation in `markdown` and I want to document how to create a text file using a bash HEREDOC.  Here is the command I want to document:

```
# cat > /tmp/answers.txt <<EOT
> value1=blah
> value2=something else
> value3=`hostname`
> value4=onetwothree
EOT
```

In markdown one uses the ` to render the text as "code" I have tried doing this ...

```
`# cat > /tmp/answers.txt <<EOT`
`> value1=blah`
`> value2=something else`
`> value3=\`hostname\``
`> value4=onetwothree`
`EOT`
```

... but that results in something that looks like this ...

```
# cat > /tmp/answers.txt <<EOT
> value1=blah
> value2=something else
> value3=\
```

hostname
> value4=onetwothree

EOT

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code block below does the trick.

````
```
# cat > /tmp/answers.txt <<EOT
> value1=blah
> value2=something else
> value3=`hostname`
> value4=onetwothree
EOT
```
````

The three Backtick means it's snippet of code and a snippet must end with three more Backtick.

For more help with Markdown refer this **[CheatSheet.](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code)**

Answer (score 114):

[The original Markdown syntax documentation covers this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax); it says that you have to use multiple backticks to bracket the code expression, so like this:

```
``here you go - ` this was a backtick``
```

renders like this:

`` here you go - ` this was a backtick ``

If you want to include a backtick in *normal* text, not in a code block, a backslash escape does the trick; for example this:

```
Here's a backtick: \`; then, here's another one: \`
```

renders like this:

Here's a backtick: `; then, here's another one: `

As a commenter asked, “How can I have a code expression that contains only a backtick, or a sequence of multiple backticks?”

A single backtick can be written inline like this: ``` `` ` `` ```

which, as you can see, renders like this: `` ` ``

The rules is, if you want to write a *sequence* of backticks, the enclosing backticks (which must be written without whitespace between them) must be a *different number of backticks* from the quoted backticks.  It does not have to be a *greater* number, only a *different* number.  For example, seven backticks can be written like this: ```````` ` ``````` ` ````````

which then renders like so: ```````` ``````` ````````

Any number of consecutive backticks may be used as a code block delimiter.  For example, an alternate form of the single backtick would be this: ``````````` `````````` ` `````````` ```````````

which renders like so: `` ` ``

(I tested this on [commonmark](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/) and [github](https://gist.github.com/) and it behaves the same so it's not just a Stack Overflow oddity)

Comment: This was helpful to me, but I'd also add to your instructions that your line can't end with three backticks. E.g. I was trying to surround ``eval `ssh-agent -s` `` with pairs of double backticks and eventually realized that I needed to add a space before the closing pair of backticks.

Comment: I think you should also add that you can have a single space after the first `` and before the final one too, to allow escaping multiple backticks.

Comment: How to render <pre>`(func)</pre> in a code block?

Comment: I can't show this in a comment, because in comments you can't use triple-backticks. But the answer above, "use double backticks around the `<pre>`" will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @geekley. I was trying to style a code one-liner that included two backticks, with the second at the very end of the expression. The double-backtick trick didn't work on GitHub without spaces inside the double-backticks. As you say, the spaces need to be balanced so the space character doesn't get rendered.

Comment: How can I have a code expression that contains **only** a backtick, or a sequence of multiple backticks?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've expanded the answer to cover this clarification.

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to change the "delimiter" from a single back tick to a double...

i.e.:
``` ``value3=\`hostname\` `` ```

should render

`` > value3=\`hostname\` ``

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't solve my problem. I think I'll go with `> value3=$(hostname)` and give up on using old school backticks in my scripts.

Comment: @RedCricket: I updated my commented with better formatting. Not sure if that will help you but you can use as many back ticks as you need to start/end a line. If you use 3 (for example) then 1 or 2 back ticks are rendered correctly. I think your solution will work as well

Comment: @RobertEkendahl this worked for me. I think the general solution to the problem is that if you want to use back-ticks inside the code block, you can't fence it with single back ticks. you need double or triple. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Addendum: At least on SO, when the code starts or ends with `` ` ``, you need to add spaces inside of backticks on both sides.

That is, if you want `` foo` ``, you must spell it as ``` `` foo` `` ```, not as ``` ``foo` `` ```, because the latter incorrectly renders as `` foo` `` .

At most one whitespace is removed in this manner (from each side), so `` `  foo  ` `` renders as  `foo` .

Comment: Thank you. This answer helped me the most because my string ended with a backtick and I didn't want that extra space.