# Escaping backticks in a markdown table

Tags: formatting, escaping, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following text for a table in markdown, I've googled the issue and reviewed the already answered StackOverflow question:
[How does one escape backticks in markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313204/how-does-one-escape-backticks-in-markdown)

I can't seem to find a solution to my problem, the text will just not render as a table in markdown.

```
This brings us to our next topic under strings, Escaping and Special Characters.
| Code | Description | Example |
|:------:|:-----------------:|:----------------------:|
| \n | Newline | "Hello\nWorld" |
| \r | Return Carriage | "Line1\rLine2" |
| \t | Tab | "Hello\tWorld" |
| \' | Single Quotation | 'Don\\'t clap!' |
| \"" | Double Quotation | "Say, \\"Hello.\\"" |
| \$ | Dollar Sign | `` `Hey ${user_name}!` `` |
| \\\ | Backslash | "5\\5 === 1" |
| \uXXXX | Unicode Point | "Alpha Symbol: \u03B1" |
| \xXX | Latin-1 Character | "Mu Symbol: \xDF" |
| \0 | NUL Character | "ASCII NUL: \o" |
| \v | Vertical Tab | "Vertical Tab: \v" |
| \b | Backspace | "Backspace: \b" |
| \f | Form Feed | "Form Feed: \f" |
```

I realize the content is somewhat ironic, regardless I think it has to do with `` `Hey ${user_name}!` `` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your backticks. Simply add a blank line between your text and the beginning of the table:

```
This brings us to our next topic under strings, Escaping and Special Characters.

| Code | Description | Example |
|:------:|:-----------------:|:----------------------:|
| \n | Newline | "Hello\nWorld" |
| \r | Return Carriage | "Line1\rLine2" |
| \t | Tab | "Hello\tWorld" |
| \' | Single Quotation | 'Don\\'t clap!' |
| \"" | Double Quotation | "Say, \\"Hello.\\"" |
| \$ | Dollar Sign | `` `Hey ${user_name}!` `` |
| \\\ | Backslash | "5\\5 === 1" |
| \uXXXX | Unicode Point | "Alpha Symbol: \u03B1" |
| \xXX | Latin-1 Character | "Mu Symbol: \xDF" |
| \0 | NUL Character | "ASCII NUL: \o" |
| \v | Vertical Tab | "Vertical Tab: \v" |
| \b | Backspace | "Backspace: \b" |
| \f | Form Feed | "Form Feed: \f" |
```

If you don't want your `` `Hey ${user_name}!` `` to be rendered as inline code, try using `` \`Hey ${user_name}!\` `` instead of the outer double backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to escaping backticks on StackOverflow is to use one of the HTML entities for the backtick: `&#96;` or `&grave;` which display a single backtick.

If you find there is any character that Markdown isn't displaying correctly for you, you can use the [HTML Entity code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) instead and it will bypass the Markdown translation.