# How to put (in markdown) an inline code block that only contains a backtick character (`)

Tags: markdown

Use case: Describing a programming language that uses backticks for comments. What should I write?

> Comments are entered with a `whattoputhere` character.

So I need an inline code block that only contains a backtick. How to enter this?

I read this question and its answers: [How does one escape backticks in markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313204/how-does-one-escape-backticks-in-markdown)

But it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Apparently, to be able to put a single backtick in an inline code block I need to enclose it with doublebackticks, rather than single backticks, producing something like this:

```
``I can use a backtick ` here ``
```

`` I can use a backtick ` here ``

But in my use case this degeneraters to this:

``````
`````
``````

Which renders like this: `````

Is there any way to enter an inline code block that only contains a single backtick character in Markdown?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This one is actually given as an example by John Gruber himself.

You can see from [the Markdown documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) that you should write ``` `` ` `` ``` to get `` ` ``.

Comment: It worked. I was trying to include ctrl+` as a code snippet on StackOverflow itself but wasn't able to do so. The suggested version ``ctrl+` `` just worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 39):

Reference: just looking at [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55587012/4561887) (over the course of a year or so :)) helped me figure the below pattern out:

### Summary of the backtick pattern for inserting backticks into markdown in or not in code blocks

##### 1. In single-line code blocks

1. Use a **double backtick** (``) at the start and end of a code block to allow a **single backtick** within it:

   ``` `` ` `` ``` produces: `` ` ``
2. Use a **triple backtick** (```) at the start and end of a code block to allow a **double backtick** within it:

   ```` ``` `` ``` ```` produces: ``` `` ```
3. Use a **quadruple backtick** (````) at the start and end of a code block to allow a **triple backtick** within it:

   ````` ```` ``` ```` ````` produces: ```` ``` ````
4. Use a **quintuple backtick** (`````) at the start and end of a code block to allow a **quadruple backtick** within it:

   `````` ````` ```` ````` `````` produces: ````` ```` `````
5. Etc.

##### 2. Within multi-line code blocks (between code fences)

A normal multi-line code block begins with a code fence which uses 3 backticks:

````
```  <-- starting code fence
code goes here
```  <-- ending code fence
````

So this C code block:

````
```c
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```
````

produces this:

```c
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

But, it turns out you can have code fences within your code blocks so long as your outer code blocks use code fences with more backticks, same as we saw previously in the single-line code block examples above.

So this:

`````
````
```c
// some comment
```
````
`````

produces this:

````
```c
// some comment
```
````

And this:

``````
`````c
````
```
// some comment
```
````
`````
``````

produces this:

`````c
````
```
// some comment
```
````
`````

##### 3. *Not* in code blocks (use a backslash before each backtick)

To insert backticks into markdown *not* formatted as code blocks, just use a backslash in front of the backticks.

Ex:

1. This: `` \`\`\` `` produces this: ```
2. And the way I even type up this: `` \`\`\` `` is like this: ``` `` \`\`\` `` ```. (Now guess how I even typed up that into this markdown answer!--3 backticks added to the beginning and end of that, of course! )

### Going further

To add clarity to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55587012/4561887), here is an example:

To produce this, which has a single backtick near the end, but in code format:

**syntax error near unexpected token `|'**

Do this. Notice the **double-backtick** (``) at the beginning and end, in order **to allow a *single backtick*** (`) anywhere in between the two:

```
``syntax error near unexpected token `|'``
```

...which produces this: `` syntax error near unexpected token `|' ``, which is what I want!

This is from my question here where I was trying to quote a bash error: [Bash: how to print and run a cmd array which has the pipe operator, |, in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71150916/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use backticks to surround a word that you *do not* want formatted as code (for example, `sql_columns`), there are three approaches that I'm aware of:

1. Surround the word with the HTML entity code `&#96;` which will produce a backtick from StackOverflow's Markdown engine,
2. Use the `\&grave;` HTML entity which produces **`**
3. Use the `\` as an escape for the backtick: typing **\`text\`** produces **`text`**.